# How to i build maps like in mindmeister.com in jquery?

Tags: jquery, mindmapping

I wish to build a site which has similar interface that of mindmester.. kinda mindmapping functionality..

wanted to know what is it built with..

Comment: Just have a look through the page source. http://www.mindmeister.com/40950677/

Comment: Thanks... looks like they used html5

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://raphaeljs.com/